# Неправильно считает работает программа

Tags: c++

Я написал программу на С++ по этой формуле [image: Та самая формула]

Но в результате при компиляции программа выдаёт первое значение вместо подсчёта формулы. Трудно описать словами. Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int i, k, n, y;
    cout << "Введите значение n-->" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите значение i-->" << endl;
    cin >> i;


    for (k = 1.0; k <= n; k++) {
        for (i = 1.0; i <= k; i++) {
            y = i*i/n;
        }
    }
    cout << "Y = " << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста :(

Comment: Ну добавьте вычисление произведения и суммы.

Comment: `y = i*i/n;` и что по-вашему это должно сделать?

Comment: @timbars ну подсчитать значение ```y``` по идее. Я вообще далёк от С++ да и от ООП программирования, но аттестацию пройти нужно как-то...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x*x%2Fa+%2C+x%3D1+to+n и сумма уже не нужна. Дальше https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Prod++%28n+%28n+%2B+1%29+%282+n+%2B+1%29%29%2F%286+a%29%2C+n%3D1+to+a и вот ответ в чистом виде. Считаем табличку, все равно уже при 30 в стандартные типы данных не влазит. Ну и все.

Comment: Раз у ваc только `1.0`, зачем аж `2` цикла?)

Comment: Внешним параметром данной формулы является только значение `n`. Зачем еще вдруг у пользователя запрашивается ввод значения `i`??? Это при том-то, что в вашем коде введенное пользователем значение `i` никак не используется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно немного посоображать с бумажкой и ручкой в руках, и желательно, чтоб бумажка была не туалетная :), и тут же будет понятно, что сия формула дает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что весь код вычисления сводится к

```
double prsum(unsigned int n)
{
    double r = 1;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= 2*n+1; ++i)
    {
        r *= i;
        if (i <= n+1) r*= i;
    }
    return r/pow(12.0*n,n);
}
```

Если очень хочется убедиться, что это так - см. [сюда](https://ideone.com/rNm7Ac)...